# How does C# handle operator overloading

Tags: c#, optimization, operator-overloading

Say I have a complex numbers class in C#, whose addition operator is defined like this.

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
 {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
 }
```

and used like this.

```
 Complex c1, c2, c3, c4;

 c1 = new Complex(...)
 ...
 c4 = new Complex(...)

 Complex csum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
```

Now, my question is how the C# compiler+runtime will handle this. Apparently, it looks like it will do something like this.

```
 ct1 = c1 + c2; // ct1 is a temporary object created by the compiler
 ct2 = ct1 + c3;
 csum = ct2 + c4;
```

Or is it smart enough to realize it can do it in a better way (less creation of new temporary objects) like this.

```
 ct = c1 + c2;
 ct += c3;
 csum = ct + c4;
```

Comment: It's not the job of the **compiler**. _compiler_ does it's magic in _compilation time_, memory allocation is on runtime - the `CLR`/ `JIT` job...

Comment: gdoron, I am asking how will the compiler generate code for this, or how compiler+runtime will handle this if you like.

Comment: Your optimized version will forget about c4 - very fast, though!

Comment: You can use **ildasm** to see what the compiler generates. @Eugen I'm pretty sure I saw the same error, must have been edited.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you want to know how the compiler will perform that?

Comment: @gdoron not any longer after the OP edited the optimized version.

Answer (score 1):

The single expression is equivalent (in terms of generated code) to the separate statements, aside from there being a named local variable for it. The JIT may optimize that, but the compiler can't. Note that if `Complex` is a value type then it's not really going to involve allocating *objects*<sup>1</sup>.

It's worth noting that the `+` operator is handled specially for `string` in C# (it's specified by the language; it's not in the framework itself) precisely to avoid this sort of thing: `x + y + z` is (or at least can be) converted into `string.Concat(x, y, z)` to avoid creating temporary strings.

---

<sup>1</sup> By "object" I mean an area of memory with an object header (type reference, sync block etc) followed by the fields, allocated on the heap, as opposed to a "value type value" which only includes the data itself, and may be on the heap or the stack. The stack/heap part is an [implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) of course, but a potentially important one... and I believe it *is* reasonable to differentiate between "just a value type value" and "a full object".

Comment: "not really going to involve allocating objects": *everything* is an object in .NET.  And `+` operator special handling applies only to strings as far as I know -- the string class may not even *have* a `+` operator in the BCL.

Comment: @phoog: Oops, I meant to explictly state "for string" - that's precisely the point I was making :) As for "everything is an object" - I like to differentiate between a value type value and an object (which has a sync block etc). Of course boxing will turn one into the other. It would be nice if there were clearly-defined terminology for this, but I haven't seen that anywhere.

Comment: @phoog: Have added an explanatory footnote - see what you think.

Comment: Yes, it would indeed be nice if there were clearly-defined terminology for this -- in fact I posted the comment more to draw attention to that fact than for any other reason.  "Garbage-collected reference-type object" would be accurate, I think, but it's not a great candidate because it's neither very convenient nor concise.

Comment: I recall seeing the term "garbage-collected heap" in Microsoft documentation, and the GC indeed seems to be one of the important distinctions.  By analogy with the distinction between managed and unmanaged types (relevant to pointers), perhaps we could use "managed object".

Comment: @phoog: I've been using "object" for this for quite a while, and I think I've seen others doing the same ("boxing creates an object from a value type value" type explanations). I don't think I've seen it confuse anyone before. Will think further.

Comment: I don't suppose it confuses many, but I still hear Eric Lippert's voice echoing in my head.  I've read his objections on more than one occasion when someone has implied that value types are not objects.

Comment: @phoog: I would be loathe to distress Eric, of course. Do you have any examples? Would be interested to see his choice of language.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your inferred stepwise procedures are correct with regards to the compiled output. The CLR is a stack machine, and since the code for adding all four at once does not indicate a need to separately allocate the intermediate totals as named variables it updates the running total in place (or rather pops and pushes the top stack element).

Both of your stepwise versions require the same number of actual operations; the unary addition version just requires one less local variable allocation.

Below is the actual IL produced by three different ways of adding the four input complex numbers. Note in my version I changed the Complex class (which I assume you lifted from [How to: Use Operator Overloading to Create a Complex Number Class (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fbs5e2h.aspx)) to hold two `double` values instead of two `int`s. I have omitted the declaration of c1..c4 in both the C# and IL code for brevity. In short, both of the inferred stepwise approaches require two extra `stloc.s` (push a value to the variable list) and `ldloc.s` (retrieve a value from the variable list) calls each.

**Original: Add all four in a row:**

C#:

```
Complex csum = c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;
```

IL:

```
// MultipleAdd : 5 Locals, maxstack 3
IL_0068:  nop
IL_0069:  ldloc.0
IL_006a:  ldloc.1
IL_006b:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0070:  ldloc.2
IL_0071:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0076:  ldloc.3
IL_0077:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_007c:  stloc.s    csum
IL_007e:  ret
```

**Inference 1: Three binary additions**

C#:

```
Complex ct1 = c1 + c2; 
Complex ct2 = ct1 + c3;  
Complex csum = ct2 + c4;
```

IL:

```
// BinaryAdd : 7 Locals, maxstack 3
IL_0068:  nop
IL_0069:  ldloc.0
IL_006a:  ldloc.1
IL_006b:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0070:  stloc.s    ct1
IL_0072:  ldloc.s    ct1
IL_0074:  ldloc.2
IL_0075:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_007a:  stloc.s    ct2
IL_007c:  ldloc.s    ct2
IL_007e:  ldloc.3
IL_007f:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0084:  stloc.s    csum
IL_0086:  ret
```

**Inference 2: Unary additions**

C#:

```
Complex ct = c1 + c2; 
ct += c3; 
Complex csum = ct + c4;
```

IL:

```
// UnaryAdd : 6 Locals, maxstack 3
IL_0068:  nop
IL_0069:  ldloc.0
IL_006a:  ldloc.1
IL_006b:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0070:  stloc.s    ct
IL_0072:  ldloc.s    ct
IL_0074:  ldloc.2
IL_0075:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_007a:  stloc.s    ct
IL_007c:  ldloc.s    ct
IL_007e:  ldloc.3
IL_007f:  call       valuetype Test.Complex Test.Complex::op_Addition(valuetype Test.Complex,
                                                                    valuetype Test.Complex)
IL_0084:  stloc.s    csum
IL_0086:  ret
```

Comment: So this means, C# does create a new object for every addition operation. right? Or does it reuse the same temporary object, just like the C++ move semantics?

Comment: @MetallicPriest It's not a matter of C# but of CIL / MSIL. But that said I should have included the IL for `Complex::op_Addition`: The last step **is** in fact to create a new `Complex` object (`newobj` op) by popping the last two values off the stack -- the results of adding the two input `real` and `complex` fields.